# Log a Call Quick Action from Contact Page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, custom-button, quickaction

I used the following link (https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-create-a-custom-button-on-record-page-in-lightning-experience/)  to create a Quick Action which opens a box.

I am trying to update the Lightning Component to actually open the Log a Call page.

I need the button to exist on the Contact record rather than the actual Activity component.  I know in Classic you can create a custom button and place it on the Contact Page layout, how would you get it done in LEX?

Comment: I think I might have a solution, anyone know how to get the URL for a Log a Call in Lightning or New Task?

Since it opens up the new page, the URL stays the same.

Comment: You have `Log a Call` as [Global Actions](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/salesforce1_mobile_app/units/salesforce1_mobile_app_actions_global) on global publisher layout. You also have `Log a call` tab option on the activity tab on Contact's detail page. I am not sure why you need to have `log a call` custom quick action?

Comment: The global Action shows onthe Activity Tab, but I'd like it to show up on the Contact Record Page, beside Edit

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly - you want to open the `Log A Call` as a dialog - from an action button.

Although you can add a custom Quick action and set it's type as `Log A Call`:

[image]

But if you do that - the `Log A Call` opens in the `Activity` panel always, and not as a button on the action buttons:

[image]

So actual answer to your question: **today this cannot be done.**

**WORKAROUND**

You can of course develop your own lightning component and do the  Log A Call functionality over there, then if you add this lightning component as a quick action - it will display as a button and will open as a modal.

Comment: Thanks Itai! 
I was able to create a Lightning Component which opens a box.  I spoke with a developer who says if I can grab the URL for the Lightning Log a Call page, it can be done.  Any idea where I can get that URL?
Since right now when you click Log a Call in a Quick Action it opens a new box and and not a new page, there is no new URL in the URL area.

Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't think that this solution will work in lightning - all url solutions usually work on the old Visualforce framework and do not work with lighting which is a One Page Application

Comment: Is there a way for it to open a new page where they can Log the call?

Comment: I don't think so. But there is a way to open a dialog...

Comment: https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-create-a-custom-button-on-record-page-in-lightning-experience/
This blog shows me how to open a dialog box, is there anyway to make that box the Log a call? Or is that not possible?

Comment: Not possible.  You have to develop your own set of fields. It is not that hard,  but you need to customize it yourself

Answer (score 0):

There is a log a call action specific to the Contact page you are on. Screenshot below demonstrate that

[image]

Since, [`Call Logging`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=activitytimeline_configure_call_task_event_tabs.htm&type=5) is part Lightning Experience activities, therefore, even if you add custom quick action with the action type as **Call a Log** that action will be added to the activity composer (Activity panel).

Comment: Thanks Mahmood.  What I am trying to do is have a custom Log a Call button on the top right, where your 'New Case' is located.

Is that possible?